# In Unity can I allow the CharacterController.Move function to ignore collisions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm using the `CharacterController.Move` function to move the player around the scene. I want the player to be able to pass through some objects under certain conditions. Is there a way to force the `Move` function to ignore collisions with other game objects when certain conditions are met in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Physics.IgnoreCollision(SomeObject.collider, collider); 
// collider is a CharacterController
```

Or by using layers:

```
Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(layer1, layer2);
```